# How to link new Sub Accounts in Twilio with Application SMS url

Tags: php, twilio

I am working on a portal where each new customer gets a twilio sub account and a phone number linked to it, when he creates his account on the portal.

Now I want to link all these new phone numbers in the new sub accounts to a TwiML application in the parent Account, so that the new numbers are able to use the TwiML Application's Voice and SMS URLs.

I have studied the Twilio Documentation and was not able to figure out a way to get this done.

Language: php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here!

TwiML Applications are scoped to each sub account, so you actually cannot assign a sub account's phone number to use the Voice and SMS URLs associated with a TwiML Application not directly owned by that sub account.

However, you can [create new TwiML Applications via the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) so as part of your setup process where you create the sub account, you could also create a new TwiML Application that is owned by that sub account and assign the numbers to it as you purchase them.

Comment: Thanks. Its been a while but will be helpful in the future. :)